# bootstraping a SparkleShare project

Tags: git, sparkleshare

I just tried [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org) as a possible replacement for [dropbox](http://dropbox.com)/[insynch](http://insynchq.com). It looks quite promising, being based on open standards.

I was wondering if someone has gone though the process of "bootstraping" a SparkleShare project. I have the initial files I would like to keep synchronized on two clients and the server (as plain files). I was wondering if there would be a way to set a project up so that I would not need to download/upload all the files back and forth (as they are readily available on all three systems). I guess this would involve some git kung-fu I am far from mastering.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial on the [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org) front page worked for me:

#### Setting up a host

SparkleShare uses the version control system [Git](http://git-scm.com) under the hood, so setting up a host yourself is pretty easy. Using your own host gives you more privacy and control, as well as lots of cheap storage space and higher transfer speeds. We've made a simple script that does the hard work for you:

```
# Run all of the following commands as the root user on
# a Debian or Red Hat based Linux system

# Fetch the Dazzle script
curl https://raw.github.com/hbons/Dazzle/master/dazzle.sh \
  --output /usr/bin/dazzle && chmod +x /usr/bin/dazzle

# Run the initial setup
dazzle setup

# Link SparkleShare clients using their link codes (found 
# on the client in the SparkleShare folder)
dazzle link

# Create a new project. Add as many as you need
dazzle create PROJECT_NAME
```

If maintaining your own host isn't for you, there are also existing project hosting sites like [Github](https://github.com) or [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) that are compatible with SparkleShare (keep in mind your projects will be public unless you're on a plan).

---

After that, just install your clients, and follow the on-screen instructions.